# How to integrate instabug SDK into flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, instabug

I'm trying to implement Instabug (crash analytics) into my android flutter app, and I'm confused as to where I should input this code into my project.

Initialize Instabug in the onCreate() method of your Application subclass:

[Image of the step from instabug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUJVR.png)

Where is the onCreate() method for the Application subclass in a flutter package? And if I need to create one, where would I make it?

Answer (score 1):

In the flutter app root,

Follow `android/app/src/main/kotlin/your package/`, then you'll see `MainActivity`.

Just create a class which is inherits from `FlutterApplication` in same path of `MainActivity`

```
class CustomApplication : FlutterApplication {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Paste here the integration codes of instabug
    }
}
```

Then go to Manifest, `android/app/src/main/kotlin/your package/AndroidManifest.xml`, and modify application section

```
<application
   android:name=".CustomApplication"
   ...
</application>
```

Comment: What would "FlutterApplication" be, and would I need to modify the android:name that is already din the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: FlutterApplication is prepared by flutter. You just use it to make custom application class as i wrote.  And yes you need to tell in the manifest by modifying android:name

Comment: For FlutterApplication, I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'FlutterApplication'"

Comment: yes it could happen, but won't be a problem to run the app

Comment: : Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.ju.test_app_v2.CustomFlutterApplication, unresolved supertypes: FlutterApplication

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/instabug_flutter
For `Android`, please follow step mentioned in `Readme`
Step 1: Add the following Maven repository to your project level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://sdks.instabug.com/nexus/repository/instabug-cp"
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Create a new `Java` class that extends `FlutterApplication` and add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application
    android:name=".CustomFlutterApplication"
    ...
</application>
```

Step 3: In your newly created `CustomFlutterApplication` class, override `onCreate()` and add the following code.

code of `CustomFlutterApplication` from https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-Flutter/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/java/com/instabug/instabugflutterexample/CustomFlutterApplication.java

```
package com.instabug.instabugflutterexample;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import com.instabug.instabugflutter.InstabugFlutterPlugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomFlutterApplication extends FlutterApplication {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ArrayList<String> invocation_events = new ArrayList<>();
    invocation_events.add(InstabugFlutterPlugin.INVOCATION_EVENT_FLOATING_BUTTON);
    InstabugFlutterPlugin instabug = new InstabugFlutterPlugin();
    instabug.start(CustomFlutterApplication.this, "2d355f559ea67051a56fce82603f8e41", invocation_events);
    instabug.setWelcomeMessageMode("WelcomeMessageMode.disabled");
  }
}
```

`Dart` example code snippet https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-Flutter/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instabug_flutter/Instabug.dart';
import 'package:instabug_flutter/BugReporting.dart';
import 'package:instabug_flutter/Surveys.dart';
import 'package:instabug_flutter/FeatureRequests.dart';
import 'package:instabug_flutter/CrashReporting.dart';

void main() async {
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    Zone.current.handleUncaughtError(details.exception, details.stack);
  };

  runZoned<Future<void>>(() async {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, onError: (dynamic error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    CrashReporting.reportCrash(error, stackTrace);
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      Instabug.start('efa41f402620b5654f2af2b86e387029',
          <InvocationEvent>[InvocationEvent.floatingButton]);
    }
    initPlatformState();
  }
```

Comment: Where are you supposed to write theCustomFlutterApplication class?

Comment: you can see  https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-Flutter/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/java/com/instabug/instabugflutterexample  , this is directory structure

Comment: Do you know how I could resolve this issue? : Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.ju.test_app_v2.CustomFlutterApplication, unresolved supertypes: FlutterApplication

Comment: I suggest you can directly download this repo and directly test it's example. after it work well. you can compare difference.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into their example on instabug github repo, I was able to resolve the issue.

1. Create a new java file, CustomFlutterApplication.java under main/kotlin/com/example/app. This is where MainActivity.kt is present.

```
    package com.example.app;
    
    import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
    import com.instabug.instabugflutter.InstabugFlutterPlugin;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class CustomFlutterApplication extends FlutterApplication {
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ArrayList<String> invocationEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        invocationEvents.add(InstabugFlutterPlugin.INVOCATION_EVENT_SHAKE);
        new InstabugFlutterPlugin().start(CustomFlutterApplication.this, "<API KEY>", invocationEvents);
      }
    }
```

2. In your AndroidManifest.xml, replace `android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"` with `android:name=".CustomFlutterApplication"`
3. In your project level build.gradle,

```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://sdks.instabug.com/nexus/repository/instabug-cp"
            }
        }
    }
```

4. Now build your project